# installing ROS if Opencv is allready installed

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm experimenting with opencv on windows and now i want to install ROS as well. Do I have to uninstall my current Opencv environment?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34252/installing-ros-if--opencv-is-allready-installed/) by [oswaldfig](https://answers.ros.org/users/2401/oswaldfig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't say for certain regarding ROS on windows, but on linux there are no problems if OpenCV was already installed while installing ROS. I guess it depends on what OpenCV and what ROS version you are trying to install. ROS Electric has OpenCV 2.3.1 I believe, so if you have 2.3.1 and are installing Electric there should be no problem at all. The same goes for ROS fuerte and OpenCV 2.4.0.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1